# rails 5 Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am using paperclip to upload images to amazon S3. Here is my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

Image upload works locally but breaks in production (heroku). I followed heroku's configuration setup found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#configuration. My  config/environments/production.rb file is here:

```
   # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}

end
```

I ran the following heroku CLI commands:

```
  $ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name  
  $ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
  $ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
  $ heroku config:set AWS_REGION=your_aws_region
```

and set the region to Oregon.

I've seen other solutions that suggest that the aws_region should be set to us-west-2 ( https://locomotive-v3.readme.io/discuss/56a7e06897e8b00d0096d27a ). I reset my aws configuration but I get the same 'seahorse' error. I'm new to rails and don't know where else to troubleshoot. All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

here is an image of my heroku log if it helps. Seems generic but I'm not familiar enough to get more detail if it's available. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Oregon` is not a valid region. It should be `us-west-2`, I believe, but check the document linked below to be certain.

I had this exact same problem (resulting in the exact same error message since a `getaddrinfo` error is a DNS failure). I was using an invalid region. I was using `us-standard` which has been renamed to `us-east-1`.

Per the [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) document:

> **Note**
>
> Amazon S3 renamed the US Standard Region to the US East (N. Virginia) Region to be consistent with AWS regional naming conventions. There is no change to the endpoint and you do not need to make any changes to your application.

So, double check the value returned by `ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')` (that which was actually set by `heroku config:set AWS_REGION=your_aws_region`, and hope it's not literally `your_aws_region` ...which I've also done in the past.)

You should be able to check this by running:

```
heroku get AWS_REGION
```